# Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.Redirect not working with Ajax call

Tags: redirect, mvc-forms, ajax

I have an `Sitecore app (9.0.2)` `MVC` application, in which I send to the Controller a  `FormCollection` object, with an `Ajax` call (because I create dynamically tabs with in View).

On the Controller, I have a redirect to a payment service:

```
WebUtil.Redirect(new RealExService().RedirectPost(postData, Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("realexurl","https://pay.realexpayments.com/pay")).AbsoluteUri);
(...)
return View("~/Views/Complete.cshtml", viewModel);
```

The issue is that when the redirect happens, Request Method automatically changes to OPTIONS and thus I get a status code of 403 and the payment form is not shown.

I have switched the `POST` request from `AJAX` call to `MVC` form submit and it works as expected. (with the price of losing dynamic content on the View)

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try returning a `RedirectAction`?  that's how you're supposed to redirect from controller actions

Comment: Is the OPTIONS request the CORS preflight request? If so you will need to ensure the payment service handles this appropriately.

Comment: @Jeroen you are right, the payment service needs to handle my request, but this is not possible, so I fixed the flow in my code.

Comment: @MarkCassidy no, I did not try to return a RedirectAction. I replaced the return View () with Content().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by replacing

```
WebUtil.Redirect(new RealExService().RedirectPost(postData, Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("realexurl","https://pay.realexpayments.com/pay")).AbsoluteUri);
(...)
return View("~/Views/Complete.cshtml", viewModel);
```

with

```
return Content(new RealExService().RedirectPost(postData, Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("realexurl", "https://pay.realexpayments.com/pay")).AbsoluteUri);
```

and in the Ajax call:

```
success: function (response, textStatus, jQxhr) 
{
   window.location.href = response;
}
```